# get top 10 posts and 10 comments for each post sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get top 10 posts based on score, and get 10 comments for each post.
I am using the following query:

```
with a as ( SELECt TOP 10  Score,Post.ID as PostID 
FROM            Post 
order by Score desc ), b as
(select  PostID,ID as CommentID from PostComment) 
select * from a
left join b
on b.PostID = a.PostID
```

This query gets the top 10 posts, however the problem is that it gets all the comments for this post. how to modify this query to get only 10 comments for each post?

Comment: Add ROW_NUMBER to your second cte and include a where clause in your final query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH a AS ( 
    SELECT TOP 10
        Score ,
        Post.ID AS PostID
    FROM Post
    ORDER BY Score DESC
)
SELECT  *
FROM    a
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP 10
        pc.PostID ,
        pc.ID AS CommentID
    FROM      PostComment pc
    WHERE     pc.PostID = a.PostID
    --ORDER BY SomeColumn
) o
```

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines would work.

```
with a as 
(
    SELECt TOP 10  Score
    , Post.ID as PostID 
    FROM Post 
    order by Score desc 
), b as
(
    select PostID
    , ID as CommentID 
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PostID order by ID) as RowNum
    from PostComment
) 
select * 
from a
left join b
on b.PostID = a.PostID
where b.RowNum <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        Score ,
        Post.ID AS PostID ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY p.id ) row_num ,
        comms.*
      FROM
        Post p
        OUTER APPLY (
                      SELECT TOP 10
                        pc.Comment_PostID ,
                        pc.ID AS CommentID
                      FROM
                        PostComment pc
                      WHERE
                        pc.postid = p.id
                    ) comms
    ) a
WHERE
    row_num < 11
```

Comment: Your code has some issues. You have ROW_NUMBER with no order by. You also are doing a subselect for top 10 with no order by.

Comment: yeah, I wrote it without checking as do not have such tables with data. so everything is possible