# postgreSQL doesn't order by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this postgreSQL query, which is supposed to be
returning

top 3 comments ordered by comment_date from

top 10
posts table ordered by post_date...

for some reason it's not ordering by post_date:

```
with a as 
      (
          SELECT  
           posts.post_id as post_id 
          FROM posts where user_id = 'user1'
          order by post_date desc --this is not working
          limit 10
      ), b as
      (
          select user_id,
          comment_id,
          post_id,
          comment_date
          , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by post_id order by comment_date desc) as RowNum
          from post_comments
      ) 
        SELECT * from a 
     INNER JOIN b USING (post_id)
      where b.RowNum <= 3
```

example: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/434e9d2

in the example it should be getting the post which has the highest post_date so like this post3>post2>post1

but the ordering of posts is not working...

I'm new to postgreSQL so i don't have any idea what's happening... actually i got that query from a stackoverflow answer just edited it a little bit: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125832/get-top-10-posts-and-10-comments-for-each-post-sql/29125938#29125938)

Thanks for answering and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordering is just fine.  How do I know?  The outer query has no `order by`.  Without an `order by` the results can be in any order.

If you want results in a particular order, *then you need to be explicit*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM a JOIN
     b USING (post_id)
WHERE b.RowNum <= 3
ORDER BY a.post_date DESC;
```

Note:  You'll need to include `post_date` in the `a` CTE.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much for the quick reply